# Python: Get item from list based on input

Tags: python, list, numpy

I appreciate this may not be directly possible so I would be interested how you would go about solving this problem for a general case.
I have a list item that looks like this, `[(array,time),(array,time)...]` the array is a numpy array which can have any n by m dimensions. This will look like `array[[derivatives dimension1],[derivatives dimension 2] ...]`

From the list I want a function to create two lists which would contain all the values at the position passed to it. These could then be used for plotting.
I can think of ways to do this with alternative data structures but unfortunately this is no an option.

Essentially what I want is

```
def f(list, pos1, pos2):
    xs = []
    ys = []
    for i in list:
        ys.append(i pos1)
        xs.append(i pos2)
    return xs, ys
```

Where `i pos1` is equivalent to `i[n][m]`
The real problem being when it's 1 by 1 so i can't just pass integers.
Any advice would be great, sorry the post is a bit long I wanted to be clear.
Thanks

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to format your question in a more readable way.

Comment: What are `n` and `m` in `i[n][m]`?

Comment: Have all the arrays the same dimensions?

Comment: you haven't been clear as to what the arrays will be like.  are they all of *shape* `(n, m)`, meaning they are two dimensional?  further, what exactly are you attempting to extract from them?  would one call to `f`, for example, return the arr[2,2] and arr[4,3] elements from each array as a list?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you essentially want to select indexes from a list of lists, and create new lists from that selection.

Selecting indexes from a list of lists is fairly simple, particularly if you have a fixed number of selections:

```
parts = [(item[pos1], item[pos2]) for item in list]
```

Creating new lists from those selections is also fairly easy, using the built-in [zip()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) function:

```
separated = zip(*parts)
```

You can further reduce memory usage by using a generator expression instead of a list comprehension in the final function:

```
def f( list, pos1, pos2 ):
    partsgen = ((item[pos1], item[pos2]) for item in list)
    return zip(*partsgen)
```

Here's how it looks in action:

```
>>> f( [['ignore', 'a', 1], ['ignore', 'b', 2],['ignore', 'c', 3]], 1, 2 )
[('a', 'b', 'c'), (1, 2, 3)]
```

**Update:** After re-reading the question and comments, I'm realizing this is a bit over-simplified. However, the general idea should still work when you exchange pos1 and pos2 for appropriate indexing into the contained array.

Comment: Nice, there were some bits there I hadn't thought to optimize. The essential problem was that when the array is 1d you call it array[i] when it is 2d you call it array[i][j], without two separate cases I don't know how to handle this.

Comment: @Roobs: just make everything a 2d array by using arr.reshape.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question, something like the following should be easy and fast, particularly if you need to do this multiple times:

```
z = np.dstack([ arr for arr, time in lst ])
x, y = z[pos1], z[pos2]
```

for example:

```
In [42]: a = arange(9).reshape(3,3)
In [43]: z = np.dstack([a, a*2, a*3])
In [44]: z[0,0]
Out[44]: array([0, 0, 0])
In [45]: z[1,1]
Out[45]: array([ 4,  8, 12])
In [46]: z[0,1]
Out[46]: array([1, 2, 3])
```